# Quickly invoking a certain set of commands

Tags: notebooks, cells, palettes

Say I want to be able, in an arbitrary notebook, to quickly invoke a cell containing the commands

```
NotebookFileName[]
DateString[]
```

What are good ways to get to be able to do this?

I have tried to create a palette for this purpose (see the image of it below), but, when I click on the palette, nothing happens. I guess I created a wrong kind of pallette.

[image]

Comment: Define a function that does that?

Comment: @MarcoB : How to define and use such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["Filename and Date", 
  str1 = NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]; str2 = DateString[];
  NotebookWrite[
   InputNotebook[], {Cell[str1, "Content"], Cell[str2, "Content"]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much; upvoted both of your answers. (I have only increased the font size: `{Cell[str1, "Content", FontSize -> 15], 
 Cell[str2, "Content", FontSize -> 15]}`)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will create a palette and print the file name and date:

```
CreatePalette[{Button["Filename and Date",
   NotebookWrite[
    InputNotebook[], {NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]], 
     DateString[]}]]}]
```

But note, that this will only work if the input notebook has a name. A new notebook needs to be saved before it acquires a name. Otherwise you will get an error message.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one little thing: Can I get the results formatted nicely, say without the extra spaces in the pathname? Sorry for my lack of proficiency in Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see an extra space? Is it in your path or file name? However, `NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]` is an ordinary string and can be formatted accordingly.

Comment: This is what I get after pressing the palette button, with spaces: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZV3LQXZgBvrDTT56vYkaA0YfzgkzJV8ICS7 There are no spaces in the pathname. Sorry, I don't know how to modify your code to get rid of the spaces and maybe get a better formatting otherwise.

Comment: I see one space between 2020 and 16. Is this what you mean? Concerning formatting, you could say: `str=NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]];` or `str=NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]` and then format `str` as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am sorry for my total ineptitude in Mathematica. I have tried this: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZJIYQXZVAoLzR9xM8jo2qLYImbPM5Ubl3d7 but only got this after pressing the button: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZIEYQXZYK7iWnvgz5Vr3VWdP9ewmBDdHLaV . Could you please just show me the entire modified code that would produce the pathname and date in plain text format?

Comment: Also, I am puzzled why you said that in my first screenshot you saw a space between 2020 and 16, and why it was apparently only one space that you saw. In that screenshot, I see the cross/Times sign between 2020 and 16 (rather than a space), as well as spaces around dashes, around the colon, and between ResultsInMathematic and s; the whole output of the button seems to be in the Input format(?).

Comment: @IosifPinelis the space and “x” you see are equivalent. Look into string formatting, formatting options of the individual functions in what Daniel suggests here, & such things as `ToString`.